# Implementing Early Stopping in Pytorch without Torchsample

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, loss-function

As a Pytorch newbie (coming from tensorflow), I am unsure of how to implement Early Stopping. My research has led me discover that pytorch does not have a native way to so this. I have also discovered torchsample, but am unable to install it in my conda environment for whatever reason. Is there a simple way to go about applying early stopping without it? Here is my current setup:

```
class RegressionDataset(Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self, X_data, y_data):
        self.X_data = X_data
        self.y_data = y_data
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.X_data[index], self.y_data[index]
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X_data)

train_dataset = RegressionDataset(torch.from_numpy(X_train).float(), torch.from_numpy(y_train).float())
val_dataset = RegressionDataset(torch.from_numpy(X_val).float(), torch.from_numpy(y_val).float())
test_dataset = RegressionDataset(torch.from_numpy(X_test).float(), torch.from_numpy(y_test).float())

# Model Params
EPOCHS = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 1000
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
NUM_FEATURES = np.shape(X_test)[1]

# Initialize Dataloader
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset = train_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle = True)
val_loader = DataLoader(dataset = val_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
test_loader = DataLoader(dataset = test_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

# Define Neural Network Architecture
class MultipleRegression(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_features):
        super(MultipleRegression, self).__init__()
        
        # Define architecture
        self.layer_1 = nn.Linear(num_features, 16)
        self.layer_2 = nn.Linear(16, 32)
        self.layer_3 = nn.Linear(32, 25)
        self.layer_4 = nn.Linear(25, 20)
        self.layer_5 = nn.Linear(20, 16)
        self.layer_out = nn.Linear(16, 1)
        
        self.relu = nn.ReLU() # ReLU applied to all layers
        
        # Initialize weights and biases
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.layer_1.weight)
        nn.init.zeros_(self.layer_1.bias)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.layer_2.weight)
        nn.init.zeros_(self.layer_2.bias)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.layer_3.weight)
        nn.init.zeros_(self.layer_3.bias)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.layer_4.weight)
        nn.init.zeros_(self.layer_4.bias)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.layer_5.weight)
        nn.init.zeros_(self.layer_5.bias)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.layer_out.weight)
        nn.init.zeros_(self.layer_out.bias)
        
    def forward(self, inputs):
        x = self.relu(self.layer_1(inputs))
        x = self.relu(self.layer_2(x))
        x = self.relu(self.layer_3(x))
        x = self.relu(self.layer_4(x))
        x = self.relu(self.layer_5(x))
        x = self.layer_out(x)
        return(x)
    
    def predict(self, test_inputs):
        x = self.relu(self.layer_1(test_inputs))
        x = self.relu(self.layer_2(x))
        x = self.relu(self.layer_3(x))
        x = self.relu(self.layer_4(x))
        x = self.relu(self.layer_5(x))
        x = self.layer_out(x)
        return(x)

# Check for GPU
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(device)

model = MultipleRegression(NUM_FEATURES)
model.to(device)
print(model)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = LEARNING_RATE)

# define dictionary to store loss/epochs for training and validation
loss_stats = {
    "train": [],
    "val": []
    }

# begin training
print("Begin Training")
for e in tqdm(range(1, EPOCHS+1)):
    # Training
    train_epoch_loss = 0
    model.train()

    for X_train_batch, y_train_batch in train_loader:
        X_train_batch, y_train_batch = X_train_batch.to(device), y_train_batch.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        y_train_pred = model(X_train_batch)
        
        train_loss = criterion(y_train_pred, y_train_batch.unsqueeze(1))
        
        train_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        train_epoch_loss += train_loss.item()
        
        # validation
        with torch.no_grad():
            
            val_epoch_loss = 0
            
            model.eval()
            for X_val_batch, y_val_batch in val_loader:
                X_val_batch, y_val_batch = X_val_batch.to(device), y_val_batch.to(device)
                
                y_val_pred = model(X_val_batch)
                
                val_loss = criterion(y_val_pred, y_val_batch.unsqueeze(1))
                
                val_epoch_loss += val_loss.item()
    loss_stats["train"].append(train_epoch_loss/len(train_loader))
    loss_stats["val"].append(val_epoch_loss/len(val_loader))
    print(f"Epoch {e}: \ Train loss: {train_epoch_loss/len(train_loader):.5f} \ Val loss: {val_epoch_loss/len(val_loader):.5f}")

# Visualize loss and accuracy
train_val_loss_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(loss_stats).reset_index().melt(id_vars=["index"]).rename(columns = {"index":"epochs"})
plt.figure()
sns.lineplot(data = train_val_loss_df, x = "epochs", y = "value", hue = "variable").set_title("Train-Val Loss/Epoch")

# Test model
y_pred_list = []
with torch.no_grad(): 
    model.eval()
    for X_batch, _ in test_loader:
        X_batch = X_batch.to(device)
        y_test_pred = model(X_batch)
        y_pred_list.append(y_test_pred.cpu().numpy())
y_pred_list = [a.squeeze().tolist() for a in y_pred_list]

y_pred_list = [item for sublist in y_pred_list for item in sublist]
y_pred_list = np.array(y_pred_list)

mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred_list)
r_square = r2_score(y_test, y_pred_list)
print("Mean Squared Error :", mse)
print("R^2 :", r_square)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A basic way to do this is to keep track of the best validation loss obtained so far.

You can have a variable `best_loss = 0` initialized before your loop over epochs (or you could do other things like best loss per epoch, etc.).

After each validation pass then do:

```
if val_loss > best_loss:
    best_loss = val_loss
    # At this point also save a snapshot of the current model
    torch.save(model, 'my_model_best_loss.pth')
```

Then, if the `best_loss` does not improve significantly after some number of training steps, or by the end of the epoch, or if it `val_loss` gets worse, break out of the loop and terminate the training there.

For implementing algorithms like early stopping (and your training loop in general) you may find it easier to give [PyTorch Lightning](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/early_stopping.html) a try (no affiliation, but it's much easier than trying to roll everything by hand).